# When redirecting a page in PHP, what happens to path and query string?

Tags: php, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

In the following redirection code, if the incoming traffic has path and query string data, is that retransmitted automatically, or must it be captured and retransmitted explicitly?

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'goose.com.au' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.goose.com.au'){
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    header( "Location: http://www.geese.com.au" ); 
}
```

For example, suppose the traffic comes in as

```
http://www.goose.com.au/mother?request=need+new+hat
```

Does this get redirected automatically to

```
http://www.geese.com.au/mother?request=need+new+hat
```

or do I need to capture the details and respecify them in the "Location:"?

If the latter, what's the current best-practice technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be captured and re-transmitted.  In a case like this where just the host is being replaced, it should be safe to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'goose.com.au' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.goose.com.au'){
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    header( "Location: http://www.geese.com.au{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to do it yourself in *header("Location...")*.

I think this is simplest solution:

```
header("Location: http://www.geese.com.au".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Please take a look at [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to know about the *REQUEST_URI* arg. I think *$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']* behavior depends on system configuration.